# Unable to access service on IIS with window authentication enabled

Tags: windows, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication, gcp-load-balancer

- We have GCP vm and services running over it as IIS server.  these vm do not have public Ip but have loadbalancer and user access the services running on them through load balancer.
  We have added the load balancer FDQN as SPN against the vm's host name. e.g.  Setspn -F -S  'host/cloudbdna-dev-admin.corp.goog' 'google\csw-dev-bapp-0'

where cloudbdna-dev-admin.corp.goog is FDQN for LB and csw-dev-bapp-0 is hostname.

When user try to access the service from window machine as client machine then they are not even promt for username and password and able to access it.

But when a user from non window machine trying to access these services, they are getting 401 as unathorisation error even after entring correct username and password.

Its something related to window authentication in IIS. (we can disabled the window authentication as it is required to be there).

- We are trying to make user to acccess the service running in the gcp vm without rdp.
- The client machine can be window or not window.

We tried disabling the IIS authentication against the service in IIS and user even from non window client are able to access it, but window authentication is required for us.

Comment: Where are all those machines? Are they in the same network and managed by the same active directory? Enabling Windows authentication and setting SPN are just two steps of many to get Kerberos working and your domain administrators are the best resources to guide you through the rest. Server administration is off topic on this site.

Comment: These are user machines, like personal laptop,desktop. 
They are managed by same active directory, the only different is their operating system, few users have window and few are having mac or linux. Currently it is working with window users only.

Comment: The steps to enroll Mac or Linux machines in AD and configure Kerberos there are rather complicated (since those non-Windows OSes do not natively support AD). Like I said you shouldn't bother yourself and should turn to your domain administrators.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.